I facing a problem in understanding the proof of the following theorem. Specially the converse part.
Let $E$ be a linear subspace of $\mathcal M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ then the function
$\mu_{E}:\mathcal M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ is defined by $\mu_{E}(M)=\frac{1}{\inf\{\|\Delta\|:~\Delta\in E ~\text{and}~ \det(I-M\Delta)=0\}}$.
Theorem: If $E=\mathcal M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ then  $\mu_{E}(M)=\|M\|$, where $\|M\|$ is the operator norm of a square matrix $M$ defined as the square root of the maximum eigenvalue of $M^*M$.
Proof: If $\|\Delta\|<\frac{1}{\|M\|}$ then $\|M\Delta\|<1$, so $I-M\Delta$ is non singular. Now, applying the definition of $\mu_E$ we obtain that $\mu_E(M)\leq \|M\|$. Conversely, let $u$ and $v$ be unit vectors satisfying $Mv=\|M\|u$, and define $\Delta:=(\frac{1}{\|M\|})vu^*.$ Then $\|\Delta\|=\frac{1}{\|M\|}$ and $I-M\Delta$ is obviously singular. Hence, $\mu_E(M)\geq\|M\|$.
Why is the author using the unit vectors? Then, he defines the term $\Delta$ and if $\|\Delta\|=\frac{1}{\|M\|}$ and $I-M\Delta$ is obviously singular. Does it hold in general? I mean the bold one.

They do not say that $|\Delta|=\frac{1}{|M|}\implies I-M\Delta$ is singular. What they say is that if we take $\Delta=\frac{1}{|M|}vu^\ast$, then both “$|\Delta|=\frac{1}{|M|}$” and “$I-M\Delta$ is singular” are true. The vectors $v$ and $u$ are respectively the right and left singular vectors of $M$ corresponding to the largest singular value, $|M|$.

Thank you for mentioning the mistake I was making. But I have one more question if $\Delta=\frac{1}{|M|}vu^$ then how $|\Delta|=\frac{1}{|M|}$ and $I-M\Delta$ is singular. Because I was doing the calculation $I-M\Delta=I-uu^$. If we set $u$ as a $n\times 1$ matrix the $uu^*$ will be a $n\times n $ matrix. Then how can we say that $I-M\Delta$ is singular.

$I-M\Delta$ is singular because $(I-M\Delta)u=0$. In general, for any unit vector $u$, the matrix $\Pi=I-uu^\ast$ is the orthogonal projection ${u}^\perp$ and $\ker(\Pi)=\operatorname{span}{u}$. Also, for any pair of unit vectors $u$ and $v$, we always have $|vu^\ast|=1$ because $|vu^\ast|=\max_{|x|=1}|vu^\ast x|=\max_{|x|=1}|u^\ast x||v|=\max_{|x|=1}|u^\ast x|\le1$ by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, and equality holds when $x=u$. Alternatively, note that $vu^\ast=vI_1u^\ast$ is already a compact/economic SVD (where $I_1$ is the $1\times1$ matrix $[1]$). Hence $|vu^\ast|=1$.

Thank you for the help!!!

Dear @user1551, please check the "If" part. I am proving it here:
proof If $|\Delta|<\frac{1}{|M|}$ then $|\Delta M|<1$, so $I-\Delta M$ is non singular. Therefore, for $|\Delta|>\frac{1}{|M|}$ we have $I-\Delta M$ will be singular. Now, taking the minimum we get that $\text{inf}{|\Delta|:I-\Delta M~\text{is singular}}\geq\frac{1}{|M|}$ which is equivalent in saying that $\mu_E(A)\leq |M|$.

This is not correct. $|\Delta|>\frac{1}{|M|}$ doesn’t imply that $I-\Delta M$ is singular (consider e.g. $\Delta=2I,,M=I$). Nevertheless, if $\det(I-M\Delta)=0$, we must have $|\Delta|\ge\frac{1}{|M|}$. So, every member of the set $\mathcal D={|\Delta|:~\Delta\in E \text{ and } \det(I-M\Delta)=0}$ is $\ge\frac{1}{|M|}$. In turn, if $\mathcal D$ is non-empty, we have $\inf\mathcal D\ge\frac{1}{|M|}$ and $\mu_{E}(M)\le|M|$.

Note that the author’s proof has a minor gap: he has not proved that $\mathcal D$ is non-empty. But this is easy: just take $\Delta=\frac{1}{|M|}vu^\ast$ as in the only-if part.

I am sorry for the mistake I have made. Now, all the proof is clear to me.

Also thanks a lot..
